# find all '&' characters in files and folders

Tags: command-line, scripts, samba, find, batch-rename

i have a Ubuntu server with samba file sharing.
i want to find all files and folders that have '&' in their name an replace it with 'and'. 
can any one help me on this situation.
thank you all
i used command `sudo find / -iname '*&'` but it didn't work

Comment: Hi tina, did you notice you' ve got answers? could you mention if (either one) works for you?

Comment: Hi tina, just curious, did you ever look into the answer(s), or is this question abandoned from the moment you posted it?

Answer (score 1):

#### Recursively: *from bottom to top*

You probably need to do this recursively, which means you need to make sure the rename is done *from bottom to top*. If you would start at the highest level for example, all files and folders below, would literally be moved, and would need to be found again for example:

```
/folder & co/some other folder/test & file.txt
```

->

```
/folder and co/some other folder/test & file.txt
```

This is where `python`'s `os.walk()` can help, to work *recursively*, ran with the argument `topdown=False`, to make sure it works from bottom to top.

For the same reason, you need to rename the files first, *then* the folders, and so does the script below:

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import shutil
import os
import sys

def move(subject):
    shutil.move(os.path.join(root, subject), os.path.join(root, subject.replace("&", "and")))

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1], topdown=False):
    for f in files:
        move(f)
    for d in dirs:
        move(d)
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `move.py`
2. Run it with the directory with all your files and folders as an argument:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/move.py /path/to/directory
   ```
3. if the path includes spaces, use quotes:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/move.py '/path/to/directory'
   ```

Comment: That's pretty cool ! So `os.walk` makes a tuple of 3 elements , two of which are lists, and then  you call move function in for loop  per each of those items in lists.  Question though: there is `rename()` method in os  module. Would that make a difference  ? is there a specific advantage to using `move()` ?

Comment: @Serg I think it is mainly a matter of taste. Apart from the fact that `os.rename()` overrides possible existing files (while `shutil.move()` raises an error), I prefer using a "real" python option :).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` with `-exec` flag to call `rename` command for all the files found.

```
find . -type f  -name "*&*" -exec rename 's/&/AND/' {} +
```

Here's a demo:

```
DIR:/TESTDIR
skolodya@ubuntu:$ ls

DIR:/TESTDIR
skolodya@ubuntu:$ touch "tom&jerry" "jekyl&hide"

DIR:/TESTDIR
skolodya@ubuntu:$ find . -type f  -name "*&*"
./tom&jerry
./jekyl&hide

DIR:/TESTDIR
skolodya@ubuntu:$ find . -type f  -name "*&*" -exec rename 's/&/AND/' {} +                                                    

DIR:/TESTDIR
skolodya@ubuntu:$ ls
jekylANDhide  tomANDjerry
```